# What is a safe way to check that a listbox is empty in JQuery?

Tags: jquery

What is a safe way to check that a listbox is empty in JQuery ? Alternative question, how to check if there is no item actively selected ?

I have tried :

```
if(...  .val() != "null")
```

also

```
if(...  .val() != null)
```

as I spotted `null` value on `val()` while debugging when the list is empty or nothing is selected, but doesn't seem to work accurately.

Comment: You mean a `<select>` element?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To check if there are `<option>` elements inside the `<select>` element:

```
if ($('#my-select').children().length == 0) {
    alert('OH NO, there aren\'t any options to select!');
}
```

To check to see if an `<option>` inside the `<select>` has been selected (only works if selected `<option>` element has a `value` attribute)

```
if (typeof($('select').children(':checked').val()) == 'undefined') {
    alert('No Option with a Value Selected');
}
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/sJdBJ/

Some Docs:

- `typeof()`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof
- `.children()`: http://api.jquery.com/children
- `.length`: http://api.jquery.com/length

Comment: @jeromeG Answer updated with two snippets of code, the second one checks if any are selected.

Answer (score 1):

I usually use pure JavaScript for this:

```
$('#select-id')[0].selectedIndex == -1;
```

Please note that `$('#select-id')[0]` converts back the jQuery object to JavaScript object.

Comment: `$('#select-id')[0]` == `document.getElementById('select-id')`

Comment: a cleaner approach might be be $('#select-id').attr('selectedIndex')

Answer (score 1):

best to use

```
    $('select#myselect option').length;
```

or

```
    $(myselct).find('option').length;
```

to get the length

ex:

```
    var x = $(myselct).find('option').length;
    if (x > 0){'if listbox contains items}
```

Answer (score 0):

tests if any item is selected. if true, an item is selected and will display the slected value.

```
if($("#Select").val() != null){
  alert($("#Select").val());
}
```

tests if any item is not selected . if true is no items are selected

```
  if($("#Select").val() == null){
      alert("no items selected.);
    }
```